# Maximum execution time of 0 seconds in Collection reduce method

Tags: php, laravel

In the past week, I started to receive the following message in the Laravel log, but there is nothing else on my stacktrace to give me any clue of what is going on. Any idea of what this could happen?

```
[2017-11-30 19:40:05] production.ERROR: Maximum execution time of 0 seconds exceeded {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalErrorException(code: 1): Maximum execution time of 0 seconds exceeded at /var/www/html/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Collection.php:1201)
    [stacktrace]
    #0 {main}
    "}
```

I'm currently using Laravel 5.5 and PHP 7.1.

Comment: We would need to see your PHP settings, most likely. Can you provide those?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the issue. I checked Apache error logs, and it showed me the URL where the error was and from that point, I was able to review what happened. And it was bug in our implementation that was causing a weird iteration that took a lot of time. Now, it's solved.